# Move UILabel's center up in UIView.

Tags: ios, objective-c, label, cgrectmake

I am trying to create a UILabel and I am setting it to the center of the view using `label.center = view.center`. But I want to move it up by 100 pixels.

How would I go by doing this?

Something like, `label.frame = CGRectMake(current-x, 100, 42, 21);`

Is this possible? Keep `x` the same but change the `y`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this : `label.center = CGPointMake(view.center.x, view.center.y - 100);`.

Comment: Ah... I didn't know about `CGPointMake`, I just tried `label.center = CGRectMake` and that was giving me all kinds of issues for obvious reasons. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RahulV.Mane No, that is not required when you use view's center to set label's center. You need to do that only when you use view' height to set label's center or frame.

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRect frame = view.center;
frame.origin.x -= 100.0;
label.frame = frame;
```